# Failing to setup postgres on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, postgresql

I installed postgresql on my raspberry pi.
then, i try to access it and I get:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "pi" does not exist
pi@raspbmc:~$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
pi@raspbmc:~$
```

I basically want to have a username & password set up in order to be able to connect securely to my database, over the local network and remotely over the internet (setting port forwarding I know..)

Comment: Did you configure your users yet? (http://postgres1s1.blogspot.ca/2012/04/authentication-psql-simpledb-test-psql.html)

Comment: thanks. as a start, I tried to change postgres password (sudo passwd postgres) and set it to something. then, I entered to pg_hba.conf and tried to change the basic rule to have password or md5 methods, but entering the user password didnt help. so where do i set the password? Also, How do I write a rule to accept any connection from the internet, with user&pass?